# Rest API Pagination and multiple loops in Power query/Power BI

Tags: pagination, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

Background:
I want extract all data from Rest API but the issue is that its URL provides data of 50 rows per ID.
So far I've been able to create a function in Power query which allows me to extract all the AGENT-ID's,

- URL:
  [https://vcc-na8.8x8.com/api/stats/agents/**{AGENT-ID}**/activities?n=1](https://vcc-na8.8x8.com/api/stats/agents/**%7BAGENT-ID%7D**/activities?n=1)

PFB,

(id as text) as table=>
let
Source = Xml.Tables(
Web.Contents(
"https://vcc-na8.8x8.com",
[RelativePath=
"/api/stats/agents/"
&(id)&
"/activities?n="]
)
),

in
source
Than I invoked this function against the Agent id's column in new table and received al the id's with 50 rows.

Issue:
It provides 50 rows per ID. I need to do a pagination in above function so that it gives me all of the rows with these all Id's.

PFB the API documentation.

URL: https://support.8x8.com/cloud-contact-center/virtual-contact-center/developers/8x8-contact-center-statistics-reporting-api#Testing_Using_A_Browser

Let me know if someone has the way to solve  my problem.

Comment: how do we know when we hit the end of the data for each agent?

Comment: The number of rows are unknow.
for that I created a sperate function and query using the same url which allows me to extract data of that particular id,
PFB,
(n as number)=> let Source = Xml.Tables( Web.Contents( "https://vcc-na8.8x8.com", [RelativePath= "/api/stats/agents/{Agent-ID}/activities?n="& NUmber.totext(n)] ) ),

Query:

let
Source =

List.Generate(

()=>
[output =

try activity(1) otherwise null, n=1],

each [output]<> null,

each [output = try activity([n]+50) otherwise null, n=[n]+50],

each [output]

)

in
Source

Comment: so why cant you add a column next to each ID using that above function which calls the activity() function?

Comment: I didn't get your point . I need to combine both functions so I can extract all id's and all rows' at the same time.